# Jenkins Job doesn't appear in the Dashboard UI

Tags: jenkins

I'm wondering why the Jenkins Job `test-pipeline4` doesn't appear in the Dashboard UI, although the job folder exist in the `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/test-pipeline4`.

I've checked in `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log` and it doesn't seem to read the `config.xml`.

Anyone know how to fix it?

```
2021-08-12 03:28:57.716+0000 [id=26]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading item test-pipeline4
com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: flow-definition
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:79)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-pipeline4/config.xml
        at hudson.XmlFile.read(XmlFile.java:149)
        at hudson.model.Items.load(Items.java:372)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$14.run(Jenkins.java:3190)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1114)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```